# Definition of topological vector space require field being non-discrete valued?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

This is definition of topological vector space in H. Schafer Topological Vector Spaces.

Def. Given a vector space $L$ over (not necessarily commutative) non-discrete valuated field $K$ and a topology $\mathcal{L}$ over $L$, $(\mathcal{L},L)$ is called a topological vector space if addition is continuous and scalar multiplication of $K$ is continuous.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why do I want $K$ non-discrete valuated field here? Obviously consider $L/K$ finite extension with $K$ a local field with discrete valuation. Certainly I can induce a unique norm on $L$ s.t. it becomes topological vector space by local field norm extension existence.(If separability poses trouble, one can assume separable but this holds in general without separability assumption.) However, $K$ is discrete valuated here.

Comment: I think that in this case “discrete” means $|x|=1$ if and only $x\ne0$. That is, Author wants to exclude the discrete topology on the base field.

Comment: @Lubin if that is the case, it does help quite a lot to clear out all the trouble I had. Thanks.